# Double join postgres

Tags: postgresql

I need to get the username value from the table "commons.user", using the field "peticion.id_usuario_gerente"

I do not know how to do a join or what is necessary for that field to bring me the value I really need "gerente"

peticion.id_usuario_gerente <-- Is an id that points to my table "commons.usuario"

```
SELECT empleado.id, 
   empleado.fecha_contratado, 
   empleado.fecha_fin_contrato,  
   empleado.persona_comun,
   persona.nombre,
   persona.apellido1,
   persona.apellido2,
   empleado.responsable,
   peticion.id_peticion
   peticion.id_usuario_gerente <-- need username
FROM rrhh.empleado as empleado 
LEFT JOIN commons.persona as persona on empleado.persona_comun = persona.id 
LEFT JOIN seleccion.peticion as peticion on empleado.peticion_contratacion = peticion.id_peticion;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add one more [left] join to your query.

```
SELECT empleado.id, 
   empleado.fecha_contratado, 
   empleado.fecha_fin_contrato,  
   empleado.persona_comun,
   persona.nombre,
   persona.apellido1,
   persona.apellido2,
   empleado.responsable,
   peticion.id_peticion
   peticion.id_usuario_gerente,
   usuario_gerente.nombre -- the column name for the user name
FROM rrhh.empleado as empleado 
LEFT JOIN commons.persona as persona 
      on empleado.persona_comun = persona.id 
LEFT JOIN seleccion.peticion as peticion 
      on empleado.peticion_contratacion = peticion.id_peticion
LEFT JOIN commons.usuario as usuario_gerente -- additional join for the table
      on peticion.id_usuario_gerente = usuario_gerente.id_usuario;
```